# Consider a graph G = (V, E) where |V| = n.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let k >= 0. Without knowing the structure of G, what is the total number of possible paths of length k from a giving starting point and a given endpoint. A path of length k is a sequence of k+1 vertices.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{\left(k+1\right)!}{2}$$

This is the formula I was attempting to get over but I'm scratching my head on whether this makes sense at all. I was thinking to begin at 1 to represent the 1st node, but I'm not sure if it should begin at 1 or 2. I was also thinking maybe to use the Combinations or Permutations formula as well but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of $G$, you can't say what the number of paths is. For example, $G$ could have no edges at all, in which case the number of paths would be $0$.

Comment: Is there not a general formula that you could find it by?

Comment: There's a general formula in terms of the adjacency matrix, for example. But if you are plugging in the adjacency matrix, then you can no longer claim that you're doing something "without knowing the structure of $G$".